# Sum of the values in the previous cell/s, if current cell/s is an error

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I've been trying to work out how to get the sum of the values in the previous cell/s, if the current cell/s is an error. Example below:

```
    ABC ASD BHP WER THY SUM    SUM of previous Error
1   789 564 654 546 654 3207    0
2   103 123 213 123 654 1216    0
3   546 N/A 879 654 654 2733    123
4   654 N/A N/A N/A 987 1641    1533
5   665 N/A N/A N/A 987 1652    0
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your "N/A"s represent real `#N/A` errors and that your data is in columns A to F starting in row B, this [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx), entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, should do it:

`=SUM(IF(ISNA(A2:F2),IF(ISNA(A1:F1),"",A1:F1),""))`

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Hey Doug! Nice answer - I realised that my suggestion with a simple SUMIF doesn't work if those are actual errors......but you can do it with SUMIFS - I'm revising my answer.......

Comment: You are so amazing! perfect!

Comment: Thank you! In all honesty, I'd go with Barry's which doesn't require an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a text value in your example, in which case you could use this formula in G2 copied down

`=SUMIF(A2:F2,"N/A",A1:F1)`

......but if those are actual #N/A errors you can use this version

`=SUMIFS(A1:F1,A2:F2,"#N/A",A1:F1,"<>#N/A")`

[revised due to comments]

Comment: Barry, in the second case the formula returns #N/A if there are #N/A error in that row, e.g., rows 3-5.

Comment: Hello Doug, yes, I just realised that after seeing your answer - I made a comment there....

Comment: Good answer, +1. Better to go this way, without the array formula.

Comment: I also tried your formula since I prefer non array formulas. This does work for a single line however if I drag down the formula, the sumif function doesn't work because it's trying to sum up a range of numbers with a #N/A included.